# jquery .attr() problems

Tags: jquery, attr

I wrote this quick tooltip function for my links:

```
$(function() {
  $('a').hover(function(e) {
    var title = $(this).attr('title');
    $('<div id="tooltip">' + title + '</div>').css({"top" : e.pageY + 12, "left" : e.pageX + 12}).appendTo('body');
  }, function() {
    $('#tooltip').remove();
  });

  $('a').mousemove(function(e){ 
    $('#tooltip').css({"top" : e.pageY + 12, "left" : e.pageX + 12});
  })
});
```

I want to remove the original title because having both is stupid. I know I should go something like this:

```
$('a').hover(function() {
  $(this).attr('title', '');
});
```

The problem is that I can't add it back. I tried:

```
$(this).attr('title', title) //from my title variable
```

but it failed. Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The value stored in `title` variable is local to that function, and is lost after the function is done executing anyway.

One solution would be to store the previous title in the element's `data()`.

```
var $th = $(this);

$th.data( 'prevTitle', $th.attr('title') );
```

Then access it when you need it (presumably in your next function for hover).

```
var $th = $(this);

$th.attr('title', $th.data( 'prevTitle' ));
```

You could bring the variable declaration outside of both functions.

```
var title;

$('a').hover(function(e){
     title = $(this).attr('title');
     $('<div id="tooltip">' + title + '</div>').css({"top" : e.pageY + 12, "left" : e.pageX + 12}).appendTo('body');
}, function(){
    $th.attr('title', title);
    $('#tooltip').remove();
});
```

...but I think using `data()` would be safer.

Comment: The variable declaration outside of both functions is the way to go.

Comment: @Gert G  @patrick
i used the outside declaration of a var and it works just fine. thx.

Comment: @Gert - You may be right, but somehow I feel better about having the information tied to the element, even though it is a little less efficient. Irrational, perhaps. :o)

Answer (score 2):

Your title variable only exist in the scope of the first handler. You will have to store the value somewhere else accessible from the second handler.

Comment: thank you. i wasn't aware that i lose that variable. i simple made a new one and now it works :)